# Matrix [[1,2,3],[2,4,6]] has a rank of 1?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, independence, matrix-rank

I found on [Stat Trek](https://stattrek.com/matrix-algebra/matrix-rank.aspx#:%7E:text=The%20maximum%20number%20of%20linearly%20independent%20vectors%20in%20a%20matrix,number%20of%20non%2Dzero%20rows.) an example of a matrix that has a rank of 1. As far as I know

Here is the matrix:
[1 2 3]
[2 4 6]

**Linearly Dependent:**

$x_d=\sum_{i=1}^{d-1}a_ix_i,a_i\in \mathbb{R}$ where $x_i$ is a vector
**Column or Row Rank:**
Size of the largest subset of columns or rows that are linearly independent

The answer was the above matrix has a rank of 1, because row 1 times 2 turns into row 2, but then they state "Matrix A has only one linearly independent row, so its rank is 1", but this doesn't make sense cause you can just times row 2 by $\frac{1}{2}$ to get row one since $a_i$ just has to be a real number, therefore it's not linearly independent.

Comment: Each row is a scalar multiple of the other, so the two rows together are linearly dependent. However, each individual row (considered as a singleton set) is linearly independent because each is nonzero.

Comment: Your definition of "linearly independent" looks more like the definition of "linearly dependent" to me.

Comment: @Bungo how come each individual row as a singleton is linearly independent if each is non-zero?

Comment: Use the definition of linear independence. If $r_1$ is row 1, is there a nonzero scalar such that $a_1 r_1 = 0$?

Comment: @Bungo does it have to be non-zero? I thought the scalar could be any real number.

Comment: What does your definition say? The standard one, e.g. from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#:~:text=In%20the%20theory%20of%20vector,said%20to%20be%20linearly%20independent%20.), is "A sequence of vectors $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k$ from a vector space $V$ is said to be *linearly dependent*, if there exist scalars $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k$, **not all zero**, such that $a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots a_k v_k = 0$."  In the case of a single vector, this reduces to "A set with a single vector $v$ is *linearly dependent* if there exists a **nonzero** scalar $a$ such that $av = 0$."

Comment: And from the latter, it's clear that a set containing a single vector $v$ is linearly dependent if and only if $v=0$.

Comment: @Bungo Would you say the definition I have up there is incorrect? I got it off some lecture slides. Wouldn't that make the rank 2 then? Because there's no non-zero scalar for both rows that when taken a singletons will produce 0.

Comment: The rank would be 2 if the two rows were linearly **independent**. But they're not, so the rank is either 0 or 1. It would be 0 if and only if both rows were zero. Since that is not the case, the rank is 1.

Comment: The set of two rows is linearly **dependent** (not linearly **independent**) because $a[1,2,3] + b [2,4,6] = 0$ is satisfied by, for example, the scalars $a=-2$ and $b=1$, and these scalars are not both zero.

Comment: @Bungo O I see that makes perfect sense thank you. I think the definition I have is incorrect as it does not enforce that all the scalars can't be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we all agree the row rank is 1. so row 1 and row 2 are linearly dependent.

No. By definition row 1 and row 2 are NOT independent as a set.

Individually, each row is independent.

If this makes you confused. I have a real life analogy here.

Consider John and Lisa who got married on January 1, 2021. They now depend on each other.

Lisa needs John to work full time to make a living for the entire family.

John, on the other hand needs someone to keep their home nice and clean.  He also needs to have a delicious meal as well as great conversation after the meal.

But prior to 2021, they are independent.  Each comes from a different family.  Each has his or her own budget, hobby and interest. Each lives in his or her small world.

Now can you argue John and Lisa are dependent as a team( which has rank 1) does NOT make sense?  No, it makes perfect sense.  It depends your perspective:

As individuals, they are independent.
As a member of new formed family, they are indeed dependent!

There is NO contradiction and No equations either!